# Creating a menu for navbar for a parallax site, built with Elementor

Tags: wordpress, parallax, elementor

I would like to know what plugin to use with elementor to create a parallax site. Parallax in the sense that the user clicks on top on the navbar and it scrolls down to the relevant section, e.g clicking on contact in the navbar, should take you to the contact section on the page. I have no idea how I would create the menu for this, as the normal menu creation method only creates a menu based on the pages I created, and since all the pages are in the index, I cannot create a navigation in Elementor with it. I have Elementor Pro, watched videos, but none explains how you create a menu, add it to a navbar so that is scrolls to a section.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a very simple process, first go to the menu, and create a menu with customlinks, then the url part of the menu item you will put:
https://siteUrl/page#sectionID

Now go into elementor, and go to the section to which you want to scroll down when someone clicked on the nav link in the nav, go to advance, and give it a CSS ID value the same as the value of sectionID.